# how to set duration of native video recorder?

Tags: android, video-recording

I want to bound the duration of the video recording into my app up to 10 seconds only.
And for that i am doing following thing:

```
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT", 10000);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, MyScreen.ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

But the video recording not stops on 10 seconds it running continusly..
So is it possible to set duration of video of native Cemara???

Thanks in Advance:
Rgards,

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `""` from `"android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT"`. You are sending this string *name value* while you should send the *constant's value*, which is `"android.intent.extra.durationLimit"`.

Comment: Hey,Thnaks. I have already used it like this...takePictureIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 10000);but didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The extra `MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT` takes a long, not an int. So if you put the `10000` in a long, and pass it in, it'll work.